# Word VBA updating LinkFormat.SourceFullName to update a graphic link

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I use the following code

```
For Each s In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  If InStr(s.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, searchFor) > 0 Then
    s.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = "http://mynewlink.gif"
  End If
Next
```

It executes without error but s.LinkFormat.SourceFullName remains unchanged. It is like it is locked or read only but I can't see anywhere where this can be.

Comment: Note that this is what happens when the image is in a content control. the code works when it is just an inserted picture

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
s.LinkFormat.Update
```